# Nested dictionaries and Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, nested, openpyxl

I'm trying to extract data from a xlsx file and I've been having some issues.
My issue lies in the last loop. The values that should be assigned in the dictionary repeat. Instead of having the corresponding values for each category and subcategory, the values for each subcategory of all categories is being overwritten on themselves and all other categories.

My hunch tells me it has to do with the way dictionaries interact but my experience doesn't allow me to solve it by myself.

Thanks in advance.

The code is the following

```
#Excelreader.py
import openpyxl, os, pprint
os.chdir('Directory')

print('Opening workbook... ')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Example.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet']
all_dic ={}
part_dic = {}

print('Reading ')

#Assigning the categories to the keys of the main dictionary
for rows in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    cat = sheet.cell(row = rows, column = 1).value
    all_dic[cat] = {} 

#Making a subdictionary for each subcategory
for col in range(2, sheet.max_column +1):
    subcat = sheet.cell(row = 1, column = col).value
    part_dic[subcat] = float

#Filling out the main dictionary with subdictionaries    
for key in all_dic.keys():
    all_dic[key] = part_dic

#Reading all the data from the cells and assigning the correspondent values in each subdictionary
for rows in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    for col in range(2, sheet.max_column +1):
        cat = sheet.cell(row = rows, column = 1).value
        subcat = sheet.cell(row = 1, column = col).value
        amount = sheet.cell(row = rows, column = col).value
        all_dic[cat][subcat] = amount

#Writing the dictionary into a .py that will be imported in the main script
print('Writing results... ')
resultFile = open('Dump.py','w')
resultFile.write('all_data = '+ pprint.pformat(all_dic))
resultFile.close()
print('Done')
```

The dump.py file looks like this

```
all_data = {'Cat A': {'Subcat K': 1,
          'Subcat L': 2,
          'Subcat X': 3,
          'Subcat Y': 0,
          'Subcat Z': 0},
'Cat B': {'Subcat K': 1,
          'Subcat L': 2,
          'Subcat X': 3,
          'Subcat Y': 0,
          'Subcat Z': 0},
'Cat C': {'Subcat K': 1,
          'Subcat L': 2,
          'Subcat X': 3,
          'Subcat Y': 0,
          'Subcat Z': 0},
'Cat D': {'Subcat K': 1,
          'Subcat L': 2,
          'Subcat X': 3,
          'Subcat Y': 0,
          'Subcat Z': 0},
'Cat E': {'Subcat K': 1,
          'Subcat L': 2,
          'Subcat X': 3,
          'Subcat Y': 0,
          'Subcat Z': 0}}
```

And the excel file looks like [the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XENal.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the command **all_dic[key] = part_dic** you link the dictionaries to the same object so when you are updating 'Cat A' it also updates Cats B, C, D and E and so on with each Cat. The dictionary will then contain the last row values for all Cats.
Use copy instead to make a new object

```
#Filling out the main dictionary with subdictionaries
for key in all_dic.keys():
    # all_dic[key] = part_dic
    all_dic[key] = part_dic.copy()
```

---

Just for interest. You don't need all the loops to create the 'all_dic' dictionary just loop one should do everything. If I'm reading everything correctly the changes to your code below will achieve the same thing;

```
#Excelreader.py
import openpyxl, os, pprint
os.chdir('Directory')

print('Opening workbook... ')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Example.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet']
all_dic = {}
part_dic = {}

print('Reading ')

#Assigning the categories to the keys of the main dictionary
for rows in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    for col in range(2, sheet.max_column + 1):
        cat = sheet.cell(row = rows, column = 1).value
        subcat = sheet.cell(row = 1, column = col).value
        amount = sheet.cell(row=rows, column=col).value
        # print("Category: '" + cat + "' Subcat: '" + subcat + "' Amount: '" + str(amount) + "'")
        part_dic[subcat] = amount

    all_dic[cat] = part_dic.copy()

#Writing the dictionary into a .py that will be imported in the main script
print('Writing results... ')
resultFile = open('dump.py', 'w')
resultFile.write('all_data = '+ pprint.pformat(all_dic))
resultFile.close()
print('Done')
```